# How can I reduce the repetitive work of this jquery source?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   $("#sel1").click(function () {
    $("#itemed1").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_01_on.png");
    $("#itemed2").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_02.png");
    $("#itemed3").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_03.png");
    $("#itemed4").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_04.png");
    $(this).find("span").addClass("add");
    $("#sel2").find("span").removeClass("add");
    $("#sel3").find("span").removeClass("add");
    $("#sel4").find("span").removeClass("add");
});
$("#sel2").click(function () {
    $("#itemed2").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_02_on.png");
    $("#itemed1").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_01.png");
    $("#itemed3").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_03.png");
    $("#itemed4").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_04.png");
    $(this).find("span").addClass("add");
    $("#sel1").find("span").removeClass("add");
    $("#sel3").find("span").removeClass("add");
    $("#sel4").find("span").removeClass("add");
});
$("#sel3").click(function () {
    $("#itemed3").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_03_on.png");
    $("#itemed1").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_01.png");
    $("#itemed2").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_02.png");
    $("#itemed4").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_04.png");
    $(this).find("span").addClass("add");
    $("#sel1").find("span").removeClass("add");
    $("#sel2").find("span").removeClass("add");
    $("#sel4").find("span").removeClass("add");
});
$("#sel4").click(function () {
    $("#itemed4").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_04_on.png");
    $("#itemed1").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_01.png");
    $("#itemed2").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_02.png");
    $("#itemed3").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_03.png");
    $(this).find("span").addClass("add");
    $("#sel1").find("span").removeClass("add");
    $("#sel2").find("span").removeClass("add");
    $("#sel3").find("span").removeClass("add");
});
```

Hello This JQuery code is a source that changes the image when you click on the element.
It works fine, but I have a lot of iterations, 
so I want to reduce my code. What should I use?

Comment: Share your `html` too

Comment: Please, create a [mcve] including the HTML and some CSS - to get the best solution. Will there be more than `4`? Do your elements have any class? Are those images really needed? What do those represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work up to selects with the number `9`. It will need a little more work to make it work with numbers grater then `9`

```
   $("[id^=sel]").click(function () {  // match every element where the id starts with "sel"
    var idNumber = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/); // get the number of given id
    // reset all src paths from all given elements
    $("#itemed1, #itemed2, #itemed3, #itemed4").attr("src", "../img/tab_img_01.png");

    // use the idNumber to concatenate the selector and set the src
    $("#itemed" + idNumber).attr("src", "../img/tab_img_0"+idNumber+"_on.png");

    // remove the add class to all given elements
    $("#sel1, #sel2, #sel3, #sel4").find("span").removeClass("add");

    // add the "add" class to $(this) element
    $(this).find("span").addClass("add");
});
```

Comment: I got 3 down votes for no reason, if something is wrong in answer they should explain it too in comment :(

Comment: @ShivPatne well your answer introduced a new class which was not needed. Then it has hardcoded `..img_01_on.png` but the balue `01` changes depending on the select. Also the add and remove class "add" depends on which number the select id has, which you didn't solve.

Comment: This is a kind of improvement but incorrect at least. Does not point OP in the right direction to dump IDs and use classes, does not seek any additional context from OP about the syntax and organization of markup to provide a better solution overall.

Comment: thank you @RokoC.Buljan for taking the time to comment! I didn't know changing the entire markup is these voted better then providing a solution based on the facts without changing not shown information.

Comment: If that's the case, why not use the power of selectors and concatenate those `$("#sel1, #sel2, ...")` etc? Than you would realize it's a neater single line, but also would require you to ask OP if he perhaps has classes, so it can be reduced to `$('.sel')` ... and the story goes on...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I completely agree! I just didn't ask and made the best proposal I could with the given information.

Comment: This answer should work, but i would still prefer storing the relation in `data` attribute. Note: I gave an upvote.

Comment: You are overriding the original `src` attribute of the `itemed#` with with the `tab_img_01`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple combination of selectors.

See sample here or in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SnakeDrak/pen/mdJEEBX):

```js
$(".selector").click(function () {
    let index = $(this).data('index');
    $(".selector").find("span").removeClass("add");
    $(this).find("span").addClass("add");
  
    $(".imgs").each( function(){
      $(this).attr("src", `../img/tab_img_0${$(this).data('index')}.png`);
    });
 
    $(`.imgs[data-index="${index}"]`).attr("src", `../img/tab_img_0${index}_on.png`);
});
```

```css
.add {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="selector" data-index="1">Sel 1 <span>sample</span></button>
<button class="selector" data-index="2">Sel 2 <span>sample</span></button>
<button class="selector" data-index="3">Sel 3 <span>sample</span></button>
<button class="selector" data-index="4">Sel 4 <span>sample</span></button>


<img data-index="1" class="imgs" />
<img data-index="2" class="imgs" />
<img data-index="3" class="imgs" />
<img data-index="4" class="imgs" />
```

Obviously, if you are using `n index > 10` you should use the [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) function.

Answer (score 1):

Expendable version of same code.

```js
function pad(v) {
  return (v.length === 2 ? v : '0' + v);
}

$('[id^=sel]').click(function() {
  var total = 4;
  var idNumber = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);

  for ( i = 1; i <= total; i++ ) {
    $('#itemed' + i).attr('src', '../img/tab_img_' + pad(i) + '.png');
    $('#sel' + i).find('span').removeClass('add');
  }

  $('#itemed' + idNumber).attr('src', '../img/tab_img_' + pad(idNumber) + '_on.png');
  $(this).find('span').addClass('add');
});
```

But I think @SnakeDrak approach is correct

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` or the shorthand `this.id`. Get to know your JS properties

Comment: I personally don't like to first remove and than suddenly add something else to the same element. Such element should be excluded from the first iteration.

Comment: It is cool to include the pad! However, I think you should use the function `padStart` native from JavaScript. [Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code.

```js
$("[id^=sel]").on('click', function() {     
      var selectionID = ["sel1", "sel2", "sel3", "sel4"];
      var itemID = ["itemed1", "itemed2", "itemed3", "itemed4"];
      var selectedButton = $(this).attr("value");
      $(this).find("span").addClass("add");
      var indexID = selectionID.indexOf(selectedButton) + 1;
      $("#itemed" + indexID).attr("src", "../img/tab_img_0" + indexID + "_on.png");
      selectionID = selectionID.filter(e => e !== selectedButton);
      itemID = itemID.filter(e => e !== itemID[indexID - 1]);
      for (var i = 0; i < selectionID.length; i++) {
        $("#" + selectionID[i]).find("span").removeClass("add");
        $("#" + itemID[i]).attr("src", "../img/tab_img_0" + itemID[i].charAt(itemID[i].length - 1) + ".png");
      }

    });
```

```css
.add {
      background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <button value="sel1" id="sel1"><span>sel1</span></button><br/>
    <button value="sel2" id="sel2"><span>sel2</span></button><br/>
    <button value="sel3" id="sel3"><span>sel3</span></button><br/>
    <button value="sel4" id="sel4"><span>sel4</span></button><br/>

    <img src="" id="itemed1">  
    <img src="" id="itemed2">
    <img src="" id="itemed3">
    <img src="" id="itemed4">
```